# Searching for a good online Job for my father

Tags: digital, stock-photography

My father has been a professional photographer during all his life.
But in my country India, not many people explore photography as a profession.
That means, he started it all in the '70s with a Photo Studio, and has been doing a good job with portfolios and matrimonial photography.

He has also been actively involved in Video recording for journalism and record keeping purposes.

But now, He has aged and can't be actively participating in such activities.
He's also suffering from heart ailments thus I can't take chances anymore.

Thus, I am searching for a legitimate online job related to photography or KPO related to the fields of photography, photography training.

Do you guys have any idea what I can suggest him to do?

My profession is quite different from photography, I am an engineer, although I enjoy it very much but hardly get time to try it out.

Any help would be greatly welcomed.
Thanks!

Comment: This is very good that you care about your father. Bravo sou.

Comment: :-) Thanks! We all love our parents, now its our time to help them since we are capable enough of doing this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Stock Photography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_photography) (or [microstock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microstock_photography)) could be an option, as an activity it's mostly performed online and it only requires some kind of small, basic studio (although that depends on what kind of photos your father would like to submit to stock). Stock isn't easy, as there are lots of agencies, licences to choose, understanding what sells and other issues to pay attention ([here's something to read](http://microstockinsider.com/))

Another options could be selling prints online, using services like [Fine Art America](http://fineartamerica.com/) or [RedBubble](http://www.redbubble.com).

Comment: Stock is only an online activity in the distribution.  Most successful stock photographers I know are still actively shooting, hiring models and locations, and working all the time to create new salable material.

Comment: True, but maybe he could work on his own pace and slow down when needed, something not easy to do when shooting events

Comment: Stock Photography was the first thing that came into my mind. but its complexity and the need of being actively involved is what I am concerned about. on the other note, I also came up with an idea of offering prints online, since he already has a good network of people who print his photos. I am currently researching the market for both of the options.

Comment: Anything else, that's not related to photography, but is online and can help someone earn legitimately?

Comment: Check the prints links I posted above, and try to find some local service similar also (it might be cheaper to ship those prints). It could be a simple way to put the reputation your father has earned to good use. Don't forget to create a neat web site to act as a frontend to your father's work, most of those print services have ways to add a catalog to your site.

Comment: You're correct. I am currently into the market study for this business.

Answer (score 5):

He would struggle to compete online; it's a very competitive market. But my impression is that photography as a hobby is really taking off among the wealthy in India. Direct, one-to-one teaching in the customer's own language might be an option. Good luck!

Comment: I would like to call our family "not so wealthy" but "much more talented than the wealth-ies" :D

Answer (score 3):

Stock Photography is a crowded market but maybe if your father shoots Indian themes, he could provide something different and interesting to buyers.  Basically, there's no need to shoot another glass of red wine over a white background but there maybe a good market for great India photos.